# Instantiating class whose no parameter constructor is not available and parameters are not known

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using reflection to create deep clones of objects. Before assigning each field to the new object, I create an object of the original type :

`Object cloned = original.getInstance();`.

This fails when the original object does not have a parameterless constructor.

I know this can be done by getting the constructor list from `original` object and then using it to create an instance but here are a few concerns :

1. If there are multiple constructors, how will I know which one was called to create the original object ?
2. Since the new object has to be a clone, how will I get the  values which has to be passed to the clone? I have to pass the same values which was passed to the original object -but how do I get it?

Comment: There are existing solutions to this: https://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Comment: I know but my requirement requires I do a custom cloner. Please don't ask why.

Comment: As you said ,when you don't know the parameters how can you pass arguments to it. Creating an Object without correct initilization has no meaning.You can as well pass null for all constructor parameter array,but again it can throw InvocationTargetException

Comment: @Aneesh That library I linked to is open source - you can look through it for inspiration (provided you obey their license of course).

Comment: @Duncan Thanks, will look into it. Other solutions are welcome in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) function. It was designed for such things.

Comment: Only suitable if all objects implement `Cloneable`. This is very rarely the case.